# ellipse and segment intersection

Tags: conic-sections

I have a rotated ellipse, not centered at the origin, defined by $x,y,a,b$ and angle.
Then I have a segment defined by two points $x_1$, $y_1$ and $x_2$, $y_2$.
Is there a quick way to find the intersection points?

Comment: What do you mean by easy? Substitution should be easy.

Comment: I mean by as few steps as possible.

Comment: These equations

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse-LineIntersection.html

work well but only for an ellipse that is placed at 0,0 and also if a line is passing through the center.
What I was looking for was a more general equations for the intersection, for a generic ellipse centered everywhere and arbitrarily rotated and for a generic line not passing through 0,0.

Comment: I used wolfram alpha equation solver, I tried to insert the equation of a line into the one of a standard non rotated, non translated ellipse,

http://i58.tinypic.com/10how40.gif

and resolving for x this is the result

http://i62.tinypic.com/15qw704.png

which is nice.

Then I took the equation of a rotated and translated ellipse

http://i57.tinypic.com/vngnwi.png

and this is the result

http://i58.tinypic.com/2rnzx1h.png
http://i57.tinypic.com/6p5bat.png

Which is obviously impractical, can anyone suggest a different method?

Comment: I think the best you will be able to do is get to the unrotated case. For which you would only need to find the eigenvectors of the ellipse. I think they work an example here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem. You should also check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761460/rotation-of-conics-sections-using-linear-algebra