# Why does an orthogonal linear transformation does not distort conics while other transformations do?

Tags: linear-transformations, conic-sections

I have a similar question to this one:

[Rotation of conics sections using linear algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761460/rotation-of-conics-sections-using-linear-algebra#)

> Why does the orthogonal transformation preserve a conic (send it to a congruent conic), but other transformations only preserve the general shape of the conic (e.g send hyperbolas to hyperbolas but not congruent hyperbolas)?

Comment: orthogonal transformations preserve lengths and angles

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I don’t see how that fact is related.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix#Overview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
|v|^2=v^Tv;\quad
|v'|^2=v'^Tv'=(Ov)^T(Ov)=v^TO^TOv.
$$
Hence  $|v|^2=|v'|^2$ if and only if $O^TO=I$.